# recursive search json elements

Tags: json, python-3.x, recursion, search

I'm having trouble with finding json elements in a nested json.
It seems that my code only finds the element on the root level.
My code is not able to find the elements recursively it seems.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

jsonString = '{"airplane": {"wings": {}, "wheels": {}, "cockpit": {}}}'

jsonObj = json.loads(jsonString)

data = ['airplane','wings','wheels','cockpit']

dfProp = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['object'])

# find elements in JSON
for index, row in dfProp.iterrows():
    if row['object'] in jsonObj:   
        print(row['object'] + ' ' + 'FOUND')
    else:
        print(row['object'] + ' ' + 'NOT FOUND')
```

I want to find all elements regardless of how many nesting levels there are in json files.
Can someone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check if all values from list `data` is found as a key in `jsonObj`:

```py
import json

jsonString = '{"airplane": {"wings": {}, "wheels": {}, "cockpit": {}}}'
jsonObj = json.loads(jsonString)


data = ["airplane", "wings", "wheels", "cockpit"]


def find(o):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        for k, v in o.items():
            yield k
            yield from find(v)
    elif isinstance(o, list):
        for v in o:
            yield from find(v)


s = set(data).difference(find(jsonObj))
if not s:
    print("All values from data found in jsonObj")
else:
    print("Not all values from data found in jsonObj", s)
```

Prints:

```
All values from data found in jsonObj
```

Comment: you should add a `else: yield o` to the end, so that all leaf elements are included